# Подскажите сайт для определения координат по IP

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps, карты, геолокация, location

Я использую http://freegeoip.net/, но заметил, что иногда он неправильно определяет. Еслть ли аналоги лучше? Желательно бесплатный и чтоб можно было запросом по API

Comment: По сути по IP вы можете определить координаты провайдера пользователя. Если это приложение делайте запрос к геолокации. Для сайтов тоже есть что-то вроде геолокации.

Comment: https://sypexgeo.net/